# remove class and addclass in jquery

Tags: jquery

In this click function why does the author remove the class and add the class again?

```
$('#alt').on('click', function() {
    $('button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.light').attr('class', 'light');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#light-1, #light-3, #light-5').attr('class', 'light strobe blue');
        $('#light-2, #light-4, #light-6').attr('class', 'light strobe red delay');
    }, 50);
});
```

Comment: he's removing the class on all other buttons and adding it on the one clicked, then add all the other classes

Comment: @SASSY_ROG so $(this)- means active class assignt to alt.Thank you

Comment: Adding active class to alt and before that remoimg active class from all button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the author wants to reset the active buttons and only want the clicked as active

```
$('button').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

p.s. assuming that `$(this)` is also a button.

you can also write it using the `jquery not`

> $("button").not($(this)).removeClass('active');